# how to redirect to another page by using image button in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

how to redirect to another page using image button placed in gridview by checking the item template(label) value in other column is equal to the given text.

```
this is my code:

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID,SurveyName from SurveyMaster1  union select -1,'Select'", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SurveyName";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "-1";
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Question,QuestionType FROM Questions  WHERE SurveyID = '"+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() +"'" , con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


protected void imgbtnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
 GridViewRow grdSelRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;

        TextBox textInt = (TextBox)GridView1.FindControl("text1");

        if (textInt.Text == "Text")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Text.aspx");
        }            
    }
```

Anyone please help me.. May be my question is not so clear.

Comment: where are you getting stuck???

Comment: when clicking the image button in gridview,this line..                    if (textInt.Text == "Text")                                 Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: you are accessing which template???itemtemplate or footer template???

Comment: what line did you write when using footer template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void imgbtnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgbtnEdit = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)imgbtnEdit.NamingContainer;
    TextBox textInt = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("text1");
    if (textInt.Text == "Text")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Text.aspx");
    }
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: same error.                                                                  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i mean gridview also with controls

Answer (score 0):

Try below: Changed `(TextBox)GridViewRow.FindControl("text1");` line

```
 protected void imgbtnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
     GridViewRow grdSelRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;

            TextBox textInt = (TextBox)GridViewRow.FindControl("text1");

            if (textInt.Text == "Text")
            {
                Response.Redirect("Text.aspx");
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in RowCommand Event of gridview

Give image button CommandName property ="Edit"

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
            {


        TextBox textInt = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("text1");

        if (textInt.Text == "Text")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Text.aspx");
        }   
        }
    }
```